# Python 2.7 Replace % (Percentage) to \ (Slash) but got \\ (Double Slash)

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace, slash

**I want this result:**

```
u'\ue8fc\x82'
```

But it always gives me:

```
u'\\ue8fc\\u0082'
```

---

**Sample 1:**

```
>>> a='\ue8fc\u0082'

>>> a
'\\ue8fc\\u0082'

>>> print a
\ue8fc\u0082

>>> unicode(a)
u'\\ue8fc\\u0082'

>>> unicode(a).replace('\\\\','\\')
u'\\ue8fc\\u0082'

>>> repr(unicode(a).replace('\\\\','\\'))
"u'\\\\ue8fc\\\\u0082'"

>>> repr(unicode(b).replace('\\','?'))
"u'?ue8fc?u0082'"

>>> repr(unicode(b).replace('\\','?').replace('?','\\'))
"u'\\\\ue8fc\\\\u0082'"
```

---

**Sample 2:**

```
>>> u'\ue8fc\u0082'
u'\ue8fc\x82'

>>> repr(u'\ue8fc\u0082')
"u'\\ue8fc\\x82'"
```

---

**Why I need this:**

I wanna turn

> '%ue8fc%u0082'

into

> '\ue8fc\u0082'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes which are used to represent Unicode characters aren't literally part of the string, and cannot be manipulated using `str.replace`. However, it's possible to convert a string with "real" backslashes into an escaped string using the "unicode_escape" encoding:

```
>>> s = "%ue8fc%u0082"
>>> s.replace("%", "\\").decode("unicode_escape")
u'\ue8fc\x82'
```

Comment: Complete and Nice Explains~ Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. `\\` stands for a single backslash. This is the `unicode-escape`d version of the string.

Use this code to convert to a standard string:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codec.decode("\\ue8fc\\u0082", "unicode-escape")
'\ue8fc\x82'
```

Comment: Easy to understand. Thanks a lot~